# Angular firebase miembro no exportado

Tags: angular, firebase

¿que tal?

Soy nuevo en angular y estoy siguiendo un tutorial de youtube y todo iba bien hasta que ha empezado con Firebase (cosa que desconocia). Total que ha comentado que debia de seguir la documentacion de angular firebase 2.

(https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/ionic/v3.md)

En uno de los pasos comenta que hay que importar

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
```

Pues despues de añadir ese import me da un error al ejecutar ng serve

> ```
> ERROR in C:/Users/Guile/angular-app/src/app/app.component.ts (2,31): Module '"C: 
> /Users/Guile/angular-app/node_modules/angularfire2/database/index"'
> has no exported member 'FirebaseListObservable'.
> ```

sabeis a que se puede deber ese error. tengo comentado en el tutorial de youtube ese error, a ver si alguno me comenta que puede ser lo que falla.

Comment: Hola Guillermo Puertas Castillon, bienvenido al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! para que obtengas buenas respuestas, para esto te sugiero leer [ask], saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Al final encontré la solución: tenía que importar `FirebaseListObservable` en mi fichero.

Lo hice poniendo esta línea:

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database-deprecated';
```